# Insert data into Access database upon checkbox-click event of ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, listview, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to make asp.net page

Criteria

I have product list. (using listview)

```
ProductID    Proudct name      Price        ADD TO CART(checkbox)
```

Now I am using access 2007 for database. C# for code behind file. I want add product in to database which is on the event of checkbox. So if user check 10 item check box  Out of 20 . I want write insert query on event of checkbox

Is it possible to do it?  If it possible please provide me knowledge/ code how can I do it?

Please keep in mid that I am new and learning stage so make it easy or put gudieline in comments.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use the OnCheckedChanged event.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Hello World!" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
```

And in your code behind:

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //CREATE CONNETION HERE
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection ("<YOUR CONNECTION STRING HERE>");
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = conn;

    //CREATE YOUR OWN INSERT/UPDATE COMMAND HERE
    command.CommandText= "<YOUR COMMAND TEXT HERE>";
    command.Parameters.Add ("@Argument1", OleDbType.String).Value = CheckBox1.Text;        
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();    
}
```